# How make Splash Screen/LaunchScreen to show once?

Tags: ios, facebook, splash-screen, launch-screen

I am having a weird behavior with the Launch Screen after I login with Facebook. (Already updated to the new SDK 4/19/2015). Every time that the user returns to the main page from Facebook login (whether it's successful or not) ... the application's launch screen reloads again. Is there any way to not allow the launch screen to reload again. I only want it to load when the user first opens the application -just once ...no more than that.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you by any chance set `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` to `YES` in your info.plist?

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work.. :(

Comment: I was wondering because having that would cause the problem you describe, not fix the issue. Basically the splash screen will be shown each time your app launches. If your app is being killed by iOS there isn't anything you can do, but normally it wouldn't be killed just because you need to authenticate via Facebook

Comment: Im starting to think its because how facebook handles the new login with fb.

Comment: I just checked my twitter log in and it does not do that ...it simply dismisses the view controller goes to the next screen in the application. It does not relaunch the splash/launch screen.